# Optimizing deployment of rails app to multiple servers, using asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, capistrano, asset-pipeline

I am deploying a rails app in a multi-server environment. The app uses the asset pipeline, and assets are being served from s3. If I run assets:precompile on each server I deploy to, everything works fine (the needed assets/manifest.yml gets generated on each box).

The issue is that this feels very inefficient. I tried designating one of the servers as primary, and only running assets:precompile on that box. The issue now is that the other servers do not have a copy of assets/manifest.yml.

I *think* the solution will involve figuring out the simplest way to share the generated assets/manifest.yml file on all boxes.

How do others handle this situation?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: checkout the [asset_sync](https://github.com/rumblelabs/asset_sync) gem.

Comment: Yes, I am using that gem. Could you expand on your answer a bit? Thanks!

Comment: asset_sync already does the bulk of optimizing by compiling only the newly added assets.  Since, the assets are then served via a CDN, I don't see the reason why do you have to compile the assets again on each box.

Answer (score 2):

Ended up solving this by writing this cap task:

```
task :assets_precompile, { on_no_matching_servers: :continue, only: { primary: true } } do
  transaction do
    on_rollback do
      notification.exception_deploy
    end

    run "cd #{current_release} && RAILS_ENV=#{stage} rake assets:precompile"

    # sync manifest.yml
    download("#{current_release}/public/assets/manifest.yml", "/tmp/manifest.yml")

    find_servers().each do |current_server|
      run_locally "ssh app@#{current_server.host} 'mkdir -p #{current_release}/public/assets'"
      run_locally "scp /tmp/manifest.yml app@#{current_server.host}:#{current_release}/public/assets/manifest.yml"
    end
  end
end
```

Seems a bit hacky, but gets the job done. We didn't want to do pre-compilation locally.

Answer (score 0):

A better suggestion might be to upgrade to Capistrano 3 (released last week), it's generally faster, and the rails plugins are better modularised. The `rails/assets` extension found in the `capistrano-rails` gem is simple (it doesn't do quite what you need, but it's simpler). And you can use the gem for migration support, and copy/modify the asset pipeline tasks into your project and modify them to do whatever you need.

Also in Capistrano three you can get a list of servers by `roles(:web)`, for example, which will return a list of server objects, so you can write a task, limited to one server which has access to the list of *other* servers, and performs an rsync over the LAN (or the WAN) to sync your assets to the rest of your machines.

Answer (score 0):

```
task :copy_assets_manifest do
  next unless roles(:web, :app).count > 1
  manifest_contents, manifest_name = nil, nil
  assets_path = release_path.join('public', fetch(:assets_prefix))

  on roles(fetch(:assets_roles)), primary: true do
    manifest_name = capture(:ls, assets_path.join('manifest*')).strip
    manifest_contents = download! assets_path.join(manifest_name)
  end
  on roles(:app) do
    execute :rm, '-f', assets_path.join('manifest*')
    upload! StringIO.new(manifest_contents), assets_path.join(manifest_name)
  end
end
```

Compile assets on a machine and download the manifest.json which is responsible for getting latest assets on a machine and upload it to all the machines.